# LDAP search for all users with a specific manager

Tags: php, ldap, ldap-query

Can't seem to search the manager attribute in LDAP. I want to return all users with Jane Doe as their manager. Any pointers would be appreciated.

```
$filter = "(&(objectClass=user)(objectCategory=person)(manager=*Jane Doe*))";
$result = ldap_search($ldap, $ldap_dn, $filter) or exit("Unable to search LDAP server");
$entries = ldap_get_entries($ldap, $result);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

more searching (with the help of an amazing friend of mine - thanks Scott Carter!) yielded the issue.  [Answer below found here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/5392.active-directory-ldap-syntax-filters.aspx)

> The wildcard character "*" is allowed, except when the 'AD Attribute'
> is a DN attribute. Examples of DN attributes are distinguishedName,
> manager, directReports, member, and memberOf. If the attribute is DN,
> then only the equality operator is allowed and you must specify the
> full distinguished name for the value (or the "*" character for all
> objects with any value for the attribute). Do not enclose the DN value
> in parentheses (as is done erroneously in some documentation). If the
> attribute is multi-valued, then the condition is met if any of the
> values in the attribute match the filter.

so in order to search for all members that have a manager of Jane Doe you must first have the full dn of Jane Doe.

```
$filter="(&(objectClass=user)(objectCategory=person)(manager=CN=Jane Doe,OU=IT,OU=Users,OU=USA,OU=yourcompany,DC=corp,DC=yourcompany,DC=com))";
```

Then you will get the results you are looking for...

Comment: Well done, [@Steve Lloyd](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4437053/steve-lloyd). Glad you found your answer. Make sure to accept this as your answer so that others can clearly see that it worked for you.

Comment: Yep, just have to wait the required 48 hours before the system will allow me to accept my own post as the answer.

Comment: Ah, gotcha. I forgot all about that.

Comment: There is a minor typo in here: "except when *the* is a DN attribute"  can you correct it when you have a moment?